# Automatically run VBA when cells change

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that uses a button to print 3 columns of data to a text file. I want the code to run any time cells A2 through D2 change rather than using the button each time. Is there a way to do this?

```
Public Sub Print_File()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim PageName As String
    Dim burntime As Double
    Dim last_data_row, numpoints, n As Integer

    burntime = Range("BurnTime_1").Value
    last_data_row = Columns(Range("Time_1").Column).Find("", Cells(Range("Time_1").Row, Range("Time_1").Column), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row - 1
    numpoints = last_data_row - Range("Time_1").Row + 1

    Range("Time_1").Resize(numpoints, 1).Name = "Time_1"
    Range("Thrust_1").Resize(numpoints, 1).Name = "Thrust_1"
    Range("MDot_1").Resize(numpoints, 1).Name = "MDot_1"

    PageName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, Len(ThisWorkbook.Path)) & "\Stg1F.dat" 'places file in same location as excel workbook
    Open PageName For Output As #1  'creating tab-delimited text file
    For n = 1 To numpoints
        Print #1, Cells(Range("Time_1").Row + n - 1, Range("Time_1").Column).Value & Chr(9) & _
            Cells(Range("Thrust_1").Row + n - 1, Range("Thrust_1").Column).Value & Chr(9) & _
            Cells(Range("MDot_1").Row + n - 1, Range("MDot_1").Column).Value
    Next

    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In worksheet module put this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:D2")) Is Nothing Then
    Print_File
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd probably recommend `Worksheet_Change` rather than `Worksheet_SelectionChange` - that way it triggers when you leave the cell rather than when you enter it (and only if you try to edit it)

Comment: You're right. Me too recommend that but I don't know exactly if msalkema will make changes in those cells or not. Generally the idea is the same

Comment: So does this go within the Print_File() or as an additional sub in the module? I've tried both options but still can't get the file to print without pushing the button.